# Moving object to front of vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `vector<Suggestions> finalSuggestions` that contains a `string` `word` and some `int` `num`.

If this word meets some condition, I want to move that object to the front of the vector, removing it from wherever it was.

I am able to insert to the beginning of the list with `vector::insert`

```
for (auto &x: finalSuggestions) {
    if ( double((x.num)/(topword.num)) < 50)
    {
        finalSuggestions.insert(finalSuggestions.begin(),x);
        break;
    }
}
```

But **I do not know how to remove it from where it is in the list.**

For example, for some arbitrary vector `{ 1,2,3,4,50,6,7,8,9 }`,
if 50 meets the criteria, move it to the front of the list and delete it from where it was, returning `{ 50,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 }`. The code above returns `{ 50,1,2,3,4,50,6,7,8,9 }`

I was looking into `vector::erase`, but I'm having problems, and its taking longer than it should.

I envision a simple solution (but this obviously doesn't work)

```
for (auto &x: finalSuggestions) {
    if ( double((x.num)/(topword.num)) < 50)
    {
        finalSuggestions.insert(finalSuggestions.begin(),x);
        finalSuggestions.erase(x);
        break;
    }
}
```

I read up on the erase-remove idiom (here is my implementation):

```
 finalSuggestions.erase( remove( begin(finalSuggestions), end(finalSuggestions), x ), end(finalSuggestions) );
```

but am getting an error that I don't understand:

```
In instantiation of '_FIter std::remove(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Suggestion*, std::vector<Suggestion> >; _Tp = Suggestion]':|
```

Comment: If `erase` is *taking longer than it should* you probably have to use another data structure, like `list` maybe.

Comment: By 'taking longer than it should', I mean I can't seem to find a solution, not that run-time is slowed. Sorry for ambiguity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `vector::erase` you need an iterator, so range-based `for` can't be used. Use simple `for` loop instead. First erase an element, and then insert it, because `insert` invalidates iterators:

```
for (auto it = finalSuggestions.begin(); it != finalSuggestions.end(); ++it) {
    if (some_condition(*it)) {
        auto x = *it; // or std::move(*it)
        finalSuggestions.erase(it);
        finalSuggestions.insert(finalSuggestions.begin(), x /* or std::move(x) */);
        break;
    }
}
```

Using `std::move` will allow you to move an element around instead of copying it, which may save you some cycles.

Comment: **if( double( *(it.num)/(topword.num))<50)**  throws an errorr "has no member 'num' ". Sorry I am not that good with iterators

Comment: @fliposs `if ( double((it->num)/(topword.num)) < 50)`

Answer (score 29):

Use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). It's a lot faster than deleting and reinserting.

Eg:

```
for (auto it = finalSuggestions.begin(), lim = finalSuggestions.end();
     it != lim;
     ++it) {
  if (it->num < 50 * topword.num) {
    std::rotate(finalSuggestions.begin(), it, it + 1);
    break;
  }
}
```

Even better, as [@JerryCoffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin) suggests in a comment, use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the pivot:

```
auto pivot = std::find_if(finalSuggestions.begin(),
                          finalSuggestions.end(),
                          [&topword](const Suggestions& s) -> bool {
                            return s.num < 50 * topword.num;
                          });
if (pivot != finalSuggestions.end()) {
  std::rotate(finalSuggestions.begin(), pivot, pivot + 1);
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `std::find_if` to find the correct location, but I definitely agree with the suggestion to use `std::rotate` rather than insert/erase.

Comment: looks more like: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition to me

Comment: @yachoor: partition divides the vector into two parts. The OP just wanted to move a single element. If the intent was to move *all* elements satisfying that predicate, than of course std::partition would be correct.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `std::rotate(finalSuggestions.begin(), it, finalSuggestions.end());` and `std::rotate(finalSuggestions.begin(), pivot, finalSuggestions.end());`, respectively?!

Comment: @j00hi: No. The goal is to move one element to the beginning, not the rest of the vector.

Comment: @rici ah, yes. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: "That's a rotate!": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA

Answer (score 2):

Your iterator makes it difficult to know the position of the element in question. You might want to try using a standard `for` iterator which allows access to the position (used by `std::vector::erase`)

```
int len=finalSuggestions.size();
for (int i=0, ; i<len; ++i) {
    // Save a copy of the item
    auto item = finalSuggestions.at(i);
    if (double((item.num)/(topword.num)) < 50) {
        // Erase the item in the list
        finalSuggestions.erase(i);
        // Add the copy of the item back in at the front
        finalSuggestions.insert(finalSuggestions.begin(), item);
        break;
    }
}
```

... or using a std::iterator ...

```
for (auto it = finalSuggestions.begin(); it != finalSuggestions.end(); ++it) {
    if (double((*it->num)/(topword.num)) < 50) {
        // Save a copy of the item
        auto item = *it;  
        // Erase the item in the list
        finalSuggestions.erase(it); 
        // Add the copy of the item back in at the front
        finalSuggestions.insert(finalSuggestions.begin(), item); 
        break;
    }
}
```

`std::vector` objects use contiguous memory for their elements, which means actually moving memory around during altering of the container. If you are going to be moving elements around you may want to look into [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) or [`std:deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/). The definition of these containers are nearly identical (read: drop in replacements) to each other making it fairly straight-forward to replace them.

**Suggestion:**

The `std::deque` is designed for optimal insertions at both the beginning and the end of the container. Taken from the site cplusplus.com:

> ... they provide a functionality similar to vectors, but with efficient insertion and deletion of elements also at the beginning of the sequence, and not only at its end. But, unlike vectors, deques are not guaranteed to store all its elements in contiguous storage locations: ...

Answer (score 1):

Anton's answer is correct. However if you do this sort of thing a lot you should consider a different data structure. Both the `erase` and the `insert` are O(N) operations, where N is the size of the `vector`. A list would be better if this is a common operation.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am only doing this once though, on a relatively small vector length (<100)

Comment: I'd do some testing before concluding that a list would be better--most tests show that it's not, even in cases that seem the most likely to favor it. The problem is that even though the deletion and insertion are O(1), finding remains O(N), and the constants are usually much higher because it typically has poor locality of reference (leading to poor cache usage).

Answer (score 1):

It is functionally equivalent to Anton's answer, but I would use `std::find_if` to get the an iterator to the element you are looking for instead of a loop.

```
//add #include <algorithm> to your source file

auto result = std::find_if(finalSuggestions.begin(), finalSuggestions.end(), condition_func);
if(result != finalSuggestions.end())
{
    auto resultValue = *result;
    finalSuggestions.erase(result);
    finalSuggestions.insert(finalSuggestions.begin(), resultValue);
}
```

`condition_func` should be a function returning bool that takes a parameter matching the type of the elements in your vector (in this case, `Suggestion`):

```
bool condition_func(Suggestion elementValue) { /*condition here*/ }
```

More information on `find_if` is available [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using std::iter_swap could solve your problem.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main () {
vector<int> myvector{};
for(int io{}; io<7; ++io) myvector.push_back(io+1);
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
cout << ' ' << *it;
cout << '\n';
iter_swap(myvector.begin(),myvector.begin()+2);//exchange the third element with the first.
cout << "myvector contains:";
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
std::cout << ' ' << *it;
 std::cout << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is most efficient indeed if you don't require the algorithm to be stable.