# Moving an element of a std::vector to the front

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `std::vector` containing objects.

Now I need to iterate over the vector, find a certain element and move that element to the front of the vector. The order of the elements (except the one that has been moved) must remain the same.

This code illustrates what I'm doing. For simplicity the objects here are simple `int`s here and the element `22` needs to be moved to the front.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,22,3,4 };
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    if (v[i] == 22)
    {
      v.insert(v.begin(), v[i]);
      v.erase(v.erase(v.begin() + i + 1, v.begin() + i + 1));
      break;
    }
  }
  // the vector now contains { 22,1,2,3,4 };
}
```

The vectors in my application are not very large and it's not time critical at all.

This code does the job, but I feel this is very ugly and potentially very inefficient.

What would be the proper way to do this? I can use C++17.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving object to front of vector c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785266/moving-object-to-front-of-vector-c)

Comment: meh I was about to hit "post answer", but my suggestion of using [std::rotate](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M2FkP5i8yRUFLuoF) is already covered in the dupe

Comment: You can you `rotate` as suggested in the linked question, or you can simply first make a copy of the object, erase it by iterator and then insert at the beginning.

Comment: @NutCracker yes, more or less. Question is closed now. Thanks.