# Moving object to front of vector pair string c++

Tags: c++, vector, rotation, std-pair

I have a question about moving an Object to the front in a vector pair. I already read [that one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785266/moving-object-to-front-of-vector-c) but I didnt know how to use it with vector pairs or better said how to do it with strings. I dont know how to point with an iterator at the position I need because in my code I also need a count number to compare the two strings or how is it possible to compare something like if(it==ite){..} (i would need 2 loops for my examples so I would name the other one "ite" just as an example.

I have a vector<pair<string,string>> Dictionary and a vector string Text where I go through the dictionary and try to find the same word from the text in the dictionary. I already accomplished that but now I need to move the element that I found in the dictionary to the front and delete it from its old position.

I´m not sure how to do it with vector pairs.

Here´s my code to understand what I mean:

```
    for(size_t i=0;i<Text.size();i++){
    for(size_t j=0;j<Duden.size();j++){
        if(Text[i]==Duden[j].first){
            uebersetzung.push_back(Duden[j].first);
            if(Duden[j].first.length()<4){
                uebersetzung.push_back("   ");}
            if(Duden[j].first.length()<8){
                uebersetzung.push_back("\t");} // These are only so it looks cleaner at the end
            uebersetzung.push_back("\t\t\t\t: ");
            uebersetzung.push_back(Duden[j].second);
            uebersetzung.push_back("\n");
            // Now here should be the code to rotate the vector so the found element is now at the first position and not at the found position
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

"Duden" here is dictionary if you´re wondering. I want to swap position of the elements from the dictionary so if the word occurs again in the text it doesnt need to go trough the whole dictionary again and instead just find it directly in the first positions.

How can I accomplish that with using rotate? Or do I need to do it with erase and insert because rotate doesnt work with pairs of vectors?

Comment: "that one post"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Duden is my Dictionary and Text is a vector string where the words from a txt file are saved and I try to find a word from my text vector in my dictionary vector and after that I want to change the position from where I found it on my dictionary vector to the first position of the dictionary vector

Comment: Should the word previously at the first position remain there when you put something else to the front? Otherwise you could just swap.

Comment: You would do it the same way. Vector operations aren't magically different because you're holding something different. My first comment is also a nudge for you to edit the question with a link. That link will likely be used to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Henk no thats the thing I want the word to be deleted from the old position so it´s only at the first position

Comment: But what about the word that was at the first position. Could it go to the old position and replace the word you are moving?

Comment: @henk No it shouldnt swap the positions. Here an example with int v1 {1,2,3,4,5} and after the change: v1{3,1,2,4,5}  so every element gets shifted one position to the right and at the new first position should be the found word

Comment: I love how an explicit instruction like "edit the question with the link" is always impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving object to front of vector c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785266/moving-object-to-front-of-vector-c)

Comment: @sweenish sry I´m new to stackoverflow and I´m using comments for my first time sry [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785266/moving-object-to-front-of-vector-c)

Comment: for most things you can ignore the exact type of elements in a vector. For most `S` and `T`, a `std::vector<S>` rotates in the exact same way as a `std::vector<T>` does. If you didnt manage to apply the answers on that other questions you should show your attempt and resulting error message

Comment: A *comment* is not *the question*. I've already edited the question with the link and flagged this as a dupe.

Comment: @sweenish Ye but I just dont understand how to do the same with my code. I´m still new to iterators but I would need an Iterator that points at the string that I want to change the position but it didnt work with it=Duden[j];

Answer (score 1):

Consider making use of algorithms in the STL library. To use them, you have to get familiar with iterators. Then you can use something like `std::rotate` and it does not really matter what is in your vector.

For example your code can be refactored in the following way:

```
for (auto const& word : Text) {
  auto it = std::find(Duden.begin(), Duden.end(), [&word](auto const& entry) {
    return entry.first == word;
  });
  if(it == Duden.end()) {
    continue;
  }
  generate_translation(uebersetzung, *it);
  std::rotate(Duden.begin(), it, it+1);
}
```

The function `generate_translation(std::vector<string>&, std::pair<string, string> const&)` should be an own function to make the code more readable.

Something like

```
void generate_translation(std::vector<string>& uebersetzung,
                          std::pair<string, string> const& entry) 
{
  uebersetzung.push_back(entry.first);
  if(entry.first.length() < 4){
    uebersetzung.push_back("   ");
  }
  if(entry.first.length() < 8){
     uebersetzung.push_back("\t");
  } // These are only so it looks cleaner at the end
  uebersetzung.push_back("\t\t\t\t: ");
  uebersetzung.push_back(entry.second);
  uebersetzung.push_back("\n");
}
```

Comment: Oh ok thats much shorter than my programm. But I dont know how generate_translation(*it) works? Do I just write a new function with the code "uebersetzung.push_back(Duden[j].first); .... and so on" and if I do that what should i return? I´m confused sry :/

Comment: Yeah, basically. Probably the best way is to give the vector uebersetzung as reference to the function and modify it in the function. I added the implementation of that function.

Comment: Ok thanks! But If I try to use your code it says "Required from here" at the line after "return entry.first == word;". So next to "});" it says "Required from here"

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be some problem with the string compare, I have to figure that out.